# Execute Command In Multiple Directories

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash, symlink

I have a large set of single install WordPress sites on my Linux server.  I want to create text files that contain directory names for groups of my sites.

For instance all my sites live in `/var/www/vhosts` and I may want to group a set of 100 websites in a text file such as

```
site1
site2
site3
site4
```

How can I write a script that will loop through only the directories specified in the group text files and execute a command.  My goal is to symlink some of the WordPress plugins and I don't want to have to manually go directory by directory if I can just create groups and execute the command within that group of directories.

For each site in the group file, go to the `/wp-content/plugins` folder and execute the symlink command specified.

Comment: Can you supply input and output examples?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goals, you may be able to achieve that with a one-liner using `find` and an `-exec` action.  I tend to like doing it as a Bash loop, because it is easier to add additional commands instead of having a long and unwieldy command doing it all, as well as handle errors.

I do not know if this is what you intend, but here is a proposal.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Receives site group file as argument1
# Receives symlink name as argument 2
# Further arguments will be passed to the command called

sites_dir="/var/www/vhosts"
commands_dir="wp-content/plugins"    

if ! [[ -f $1 ]] ; then
  echo "Site list not found : $1"
  exit
fi

while IFS= read -r site
do
  site_dir="$sites_dir/$site"
  if ! [[ -d $site_dir ]] ; then
    echo "Unknown site : $site"
    continue
  fi
  command="$site_dir/$commands_dir/$2"
  if ! [[ -x $command ]] ; then
    echo "Missing or non-executable command : $command"
    continue
  fi
  "$command" "${@:3}"
done <"$1"
```

Comment: I'm a little new to the bash scripting so let me explain a bit more what I need and maybe you can tell me if your script accomplishes that.  I appreciate you helping with this.

I have a group text file called prod.txt and lets say another one called testing.txt.  Each text file has top level directory names for the Wordpress installs such as site1 site2 etc..

I want to only loop through top level directories that are contained with the specified text file only.

Comment: I want to then enter the wp-content/plugins directory in each wordpress install and run a command to first check to see if a folder for a plugin "wp-rocket" or a symlink already exist.  If either exists, delete the folder or symlink.  The final command would be to create a new symlink:

Example Command: 
`ln -s /var/www/repositories/wp-rocket wp-rocket`